# Compatibility Test of Apollo Client Subscription with React 18 Server Components

Tags: next.js, subscription, emotion-js

I am currently working on a project using Next.js 12 and Apollo Client for GraphQL subscriptions. My project is heavily reliant on Apollo Client's subscription feature, and I am exploring the possibility of integrating React 18's server components into our setup because we are using Emotion.js for styling, and Emotion.js is still pending support.

Here's my dilemma: To test the compatibility of Apollo Client subscriptions with React 18 server components, it seems necessary to upgrade to Next.js 14. However, upgrading to Next.js 14 poses significant challenges for our project at this stage.

Could anyone provide insights or share experiences regarding:

1. The compatibility of Apollo Client subscriptions with React 18 server components, particularly in the context of Next.js 12.
2. Any potential challenges or considerations we should be aware of before attempting to integrate these technologies.
3. If an upgrade to Next.js 14 is inevitable for this integration, what would be the best practices to handle this transition smoothly without disrupting our current project setup?

Any guidance, suggestions, or references to relevant resources would be immensely helpful.

Comment: Probably doesn't help much but I think you can upgrade to Next.js 13.4+ to use React Server Components

Comment: @grekier Upgrading to Next.js 13.4+ for React Server Components is an option, but it's unclear if it supports Emotion.js. (https://github.com/emotion-js/emotion/issues/2978)